# How to Resolve Error NU1101 in ASP.Net and React Project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    webapi  C:\Users\meena\source\repos\Solution3\webapi\webapi.csproj  1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  webapi  C:\Users\meena\source\repos\Solution3\webapi\webapi.csproj  1

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio and created a new project (ASP.Net & React). I get this error while run the project.

Do i have to install any package? if so how?